# How to take today's date and onward only not previous date?

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I want to insert today's date and onward only not previous date to insert into data base but it takes date from tomorrow and onwards not today's

```
var now = moment(new Date());
var mDate = moment(new Date($('.meetingDate').val())).format("M/D/YYYY");
//now.format("yyyy/mm/dd");
var duration = moment.duration(now.diff(mDate));
var days = duration.asDays();
//alert(now + mDate);
alert(days);
if (days > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Please enter valid date");
    $validation = false;
}
```

Comment: @Satpal Starting From today... Er... Why did you ask that question?

Comment: @pallavi: can you reproduce the problem in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you calculate, it already completes the day, and takes the next day in account. So, if it is more than 12:00:00 am, you need to calculate using previous day. So, what you do is:

```
var myDate = new Date();
if (myDate.getHours() != 0 && myDate.getMinutes() != 0 && myDate.getSeconds() != 0 && myDate.getMilliseconds() != 0)
  myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 1);
var now = moment(myDate);
var mDate = moment(new Date($('.meetingDate').val())).format("M/D/YYYY");
//now.format("yyyy/mm/dd");
var duration = moment.duration(now.diff(mDate));
var days = duration.asDays();
//alert(now + mDate);
alert(days);
if (days > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Please enter valid date");
    $validation = false;
}
```

This should work out.

Or in a cleaner way, you can also set the new date's time to be `0:00:00:0000`.

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setHours(0)
myDate.setMinutes(0)
myDate.setSeconds(0)
myDate.setMilliseconds(0)
```